# converting certain date (like "today 10.00 a.m.) to time_t

Tags: c++

I want to convert such date `today, 10.00 A.M.` to `time_t`. What is easiest way to do this? I wrote such code (not tested):

```
time_t     now = time(0);

struct tm  tstruct;
tstruct = *localtime(&now);
tstruct.tm_hour = 10;
tstruct.tm_min = 0;
tstruct.tm_sec = 0;

time_t todayTenOClock = mktime(&tstruct);
```

Here I convert `time_t` to `tstruct` set time to 10 o'clock and convert back to `time_t`. Can you suggest something simpler than this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a library for that or write a small script that does the parsing of `today`. Most libraries only do absolute representations like `Monday`.
Furthermore, for doing such [time_get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/time_get/) is a good starting point since it is in the standard.

Another simplistic way of parsing is by using `sscanf`.

```
int hour, min;
sscanf(buffer, "today, %2d:%2d",
    &hour,
    &min);
```

Comment: i don't have such string as "today, 10:00". it's in my mind. i just need to represent "today, 10:00" in my program as time_t. For example I know that shop opens today at 10 oclock, i need `time_t shopOpenTime` in my program.